Infer Type guarded Value from object member function and use it in another member function parameter
type ActionType = ActionTypeA | ActionTypeB | ActionTypeC;


type ActionHandlerType<
  PayloadType extends Object,
  ActionParamType extends ActionType,
> = {
  isTypeOfAction: (action: ActionType) => action is ActionParamType;
  handleAction: (action?: ActionParamType, payload?: PayloadType) => void;
};


Considering the above example. I want to restructure the ActionHandlerType type in such a way that I don't need to pass the second generic ActionParamType and the 'action' parameter type in the handleAction function should automatically infer from the return type (one of ActionType) from the isTypeOfAction.
Something like..
type PayloadType = { payload: 'test'}

// Not passing the second param.
export function someFunction(
): ActionHandlerType<PayloadType> {

  return {
    isTypeOfAction,
    handleAction,
  };

  function isTypeOfAction(action: ActionType): action is ActionTypeA {
    return action.type === 'A';
  }

  // It should automatically infer ActionTypeA from the isTypeOfAction function return type.
  function handleAction(action: ActionTypeA, record: {}): void {
    //..
  }
}



could you provide full code on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ without errors?

Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and get to work on it. Right now you don't have ActionTypeA or any related types declared for us, so we're sort of stuck.
